# Issue nginx worker_connections is not enough

Tags: nginx

We recently had many error 500 on our backend queries. In nginx logs, we have found this particular error : “worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream”.

In nginx conf, we have changed the worker_connections number from 768 to 2000, and this has solved the issue until now.

1. Is it the correct fix to the error we faced ?
2. Does this change represent a risk to face any other issue ?
3. Is there a limit to that number ?

Comment: This means that your upstream is not fast enough to cope with such amount of incoming requests. You can raise the value to 20 000 or even 50 000 - but soon or later you will hit the limits of the hardware. Maybe it's time to consider switching to HAproxy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to know this limit, and to monitor the utilization percentage ?

Comment: It depends on too many variables - that's why you need to measure it through benchmarking. You don't know where the bottleneck is - could be the database, the backend, the amount of requests ... You should monitor several things - network traffic, number of incoming requests to nginX, number of requests to the upstream, a histogram of the time it takes for each request to be fulfilled. Then you will see which endpoints are slow or whether you need more upstreams.